# R: Subset dataframe based on list of allowed factor levels

Tags: r, select, dataframe, subset, data-manipulation

I am on the lookout for a function that would return the rows in a dataframe `mydata`

```
mydata=data.frame(group1=c(rep("MALE",6),rep("FEMALE",6)),group2=c(rep("TREATED",3),rep("UNTREATED",3)))
mydata
   group1    group2
1    MALE   TREATED
2    MALE   TREATED
3    MALE   TREATED
4    MALE UNTREATED
5    MALE UNTREATED
6    MALE UNTREATED
7  FEMALE   TREATED
8  FEMALE   TREATED
9  FEMALE   TREATED
10 FEMALE UNTREATED
11 FEMALE UNTREATED
12 FEMALE UNTREATED
```

for which columns are equal to particular factor levels, specified as a list

```
selection=list(group1="MALE",group2="TREATED")
```

In this example, this function would return a vector of selected rows

```
c(1,2,3)
```

What would be the easiest and fastest way to do this, without using loops etc?

PS The list `selection` could be of any length, and there could be any number of columns in my dataframe of any name.

(I know `subset`, but this is not quite what I am looking for)

EDIT: A function I just made to do the above is the following, but it is not elegant, so I was just wondering if there are already any built-in functions to do what I want :

```
mydata=data.frame(group1=c(rep("MALE",6),rep("FEMALE",6)),group2=c(rep("TREATED",3),rep("UNTREATED",3)))
selection=list(group1="MALE",group2="TREATED")

selrows=function(mydata,selection) {
nms=names(selection)
sel=data.frame(matrix(TRUE,nrow=nrow(mydata),ncol=length(nms)))
for (i in 1:length(nms)) { sel[,i]=(mydata[,nms[[i]]]==selection[nms[[i]]][[1]]) }
which(apply(sel*1,1,prod)==1)
}

selrows(mydata,selection)
1 2 3
```

Comment: hmm.. Isn't this just `with(mydata, mydata[group1 == selection$group1 & group2 == selection$group2, ])`?

Comment: Or just a `which(mydata$group1 == selection[[1]] & mydata$group2 == selection[[2]])`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
which(mydata[,1] %in% unlist(selection) & mydata[,2] %in% unlist(selection))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Yes, but I was on the lookout for a function that would take any length of list with selection conditions, not just one particular example

Comment: in this case `which(mydata$group1 %in% selection[[1]] & mydata$group2 %in% selection[[2]])`

Comment: Still not quite - thing is that the columns in my dataframe could have any name, and could still contain additional numeric columns as well - ie I am looking for a generic function as opposed to a specific solution to this particular example

Comment: sorry but your reproducible example is unclear and not reflecting what you want. Can you give us another example of data.frame and selection list?

Comment: Sorry - I added a worked example, with an example function to do what I wanted, but I was just wondering if there are more elegant ways to do this kind of thing...